# Simple hierarchical listing in PyQT

Tags: user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4, hierarchy

I'm trying to create a UI with 3 columns - when you select an item in the left column, the select item is passed to a function, and it returns the items for the middle column (and of course same for selecting items in the middle column)

Should be simple, but I can't find any easy way to do this..

I first tried QColumnView, as it seemed perfect.. however implementing the QAbstractItemModel seems excessively complicated, and I couldn't find any useful examples of this.

Next, since there is a fixed number of levels, I made three QListView, and modified [this example QAbstractListModel](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/pyqt-43-simple-qabstractlistmodel/)

..however there seemed to be no useful signal I could use to trigger the updating of the other levels of the hierarchy. According to the PyQT docs, [QListView](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qlistview.html) only has the "indexesMoved" signal. There is also "clicked" and "pressed", however these didn't trigger when changing items with the keyboard

The last options is QListWidget, which would work as it has the required signals (itemChanged etc), but the way list items are created is a bit tedious (making QListWidgetItem with the parent set to the QListWidget instance)

Edit: `QListWidget` does pretty much what I need:

```
self.first_column = QListWidget()
self.first_column.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.update_second_column)
```

Comment: "...there seemed to be no useful signal" - Can you define what you mean by "useful signal?" I don't know exactly what events you're interested in based on your post.

Comment: @KalebPederson a signal that would be triggered when the selection changes, so I could update the next level in the hierarchy. Think Jeannot's answer does what I need

Comment: Yes, if you want to be notified when the selection changes you should watch the `selectionModel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any `QAbastractItemView` has a [`QItemSelectionModel`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qitemselectionmodel.html) accessible via the [`selectionModel`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel) method.
The QItemSelectionModel has signals that may help you:

```
currentChanged ( const QModelIndex & current, const QModelIndex & previous )
currentColumnChanged ( const QModelIndex & current, const QModelIndex & previous )
currentRowChanged ( const QModelIndex & current, const QModelIndex & previous )
selectionChanged ( const QItemSelection & selected, const QItemSelection & deselected )
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Aha, that sounds like what I was looking for! Not had a chance to test yet - but I guess I can do something like `self.myQListView.selectionModel().currentChanged.connect(self.mycallback)` ?

Answer (score 1):

`QListView` inherits from `QAbstractItemView` (I think you knew this), so it gets [a few signals](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qabstractitemview.html#clicked), hopefully one (or a few) of them works for you.

This is working for me (connect signals when initializing your `QMainWindow` or main `QWidget`, as in the SaltyCrane example):

```
connect(your_list_view, SIGNAL("clicked(const QModelIndex&)"), handler_slot)
```

...

```
def handler_slot(idx):
    #idx is a QModelIndex
    #QModelIndex.data() returns a QVariant, Qt4's generic data container
    celldata = idx.data()
    #Choose the proper datatype to ask the QVariant for (e.g. QVariant.toInt())
    actualvalue = celldata.toInt()
    #QVariant.toInt() happens to return a tuple
    print actualvalue[0]
```

Depending on the type of data in your model, you'll want to [choose the right data type to ask `QVariant` for](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qvariant.html).

The sneaky part here is getting the `QListView` to tell you which cell was clicked (i.e. using `clicked(const QModelIndex&)` vs `clicked()`). I think I spent some time looking at the C++ documentation for Qt4 before I realized you could get more out of the signals.

From here, I would have the `handler_slot()` call a `setData()` method on the model for your second `QListView` (using data generated by the function you originally planned to use).

I'd be glad to elaborate if I haven't quite answered your question.

**Edit:** Working with arrow keys

Hmm, it seems weird that there isn't a default `QListView` signal for arrow movement, but we can make our own.

(This almost seems out-of-style for Qt4's signals and slots modus operandi)

`QListView` reimplements a method `keyPressEvent(self, QKeyEvent)` which acts as a callback function when certain keys are pressed. [You can read more](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qabstractitemview.html#keyPressEvent). We can use this to grab the keyevent(s) that we want, and emit our own signal.

```
class ArrowableListView(QListView):
    def keyPressEvent(self, keyevent):
        #Maintain original functionality by calling QListView's version
        QListView.keyPressEvent(self, keyevent)

        #QListView.selectedIndexes returns a list of selected cells, I'm just taking the first one here
        idx = self.selectedIndexes()[0]

        #We'll emit a signal that you can connect to your custom handler
        self.emit(SIGNAL("my_signal"), idx)
```

Once a keypress occurs, we ask the `QListView` what the selected indices (!) are. Of course, you can choose to [filter out certain keys](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qkeyevent.html) and choose whether to handle multiple selected cells (I think you can set a selection mode where this isn't possible, see `QListView` documentation).

Now that we have the selected indices (list of `QModelIndex`), we pass the first one (a `QModelIndex`) along with our signal. Because we're defining this signal in python, we don't *have to* set a function prototype; I have no idea if this is bad style.

Now all you have to do is connect the signal to a handler:

```
self.connect(your_list_view, SIGNAL("my_signal"), handler_slot)
```

and write your handler.

I hope this isn't too nasty of a workaround.

Comment: QTableView is an alternative to QListView which will let you dynamically change the number of columns you want.

Comment: Hm, the clicked etc are just for mouse-activation (except one which triggers when you press enter) - there's a selectionChanged slot, but that doesn't seem helpful to me..? Annoyingly [in Qt 3.3](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/3.3/qlistview.html) there was a selectionChanged signal, but now it's gone, and and there's nothing selection-related in QAbstractItemView

Comment: I'm not sure if you get a notification of an edit, so here's a just-in-case notification.

Comment: @dbr You now need to use the [selectionModel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel) to get at the selection events as they've been a bit more decoupled.